# How do I make a function to show/hide different objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a minimize button which sets the visibility of the selection to `'hidden'`.

I also have a maximize button which sets the visibility of the selection to `'visible'`.

Now I want to do this with only one button, but be able to pass through different selections to the function this button calls.

I can easily do this if I was only using the function on one object. For example, I would create a variable, say, hidden=false. Once I click the button it would check what hidden is equal to. If it is true then it would show the selection then change it to false. If it is false, it would hide the selection and change it to true.

Now I want to do this so I can pass objects through to one function and for that function to then check what the hidden value for that selection is.

I want to make a function as I want to be able to re-use this code, rather than having to do alot of if statements everytime I want to show/hide something.

What I have already.

```
//Pseudo code of buttons
MinimizeButton = onClick(hideThis(selection1));
MaximizeButton = onClick(ShowThis(selection1));

function hideThis(selection){
selection.classed("hidden", true);
}
function showThis(selection){
selection.classed("hidden", false);
}

.hidden{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

I want to be able to do this with one button rather than two as I have at the moment

Comment: Show us the code and we can anticipate and generalize.... eagerly waiting....... Hands are on keyboard to start editing....

Comment: @Mouser updated question with code i have atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a class on the buttons (`button.toggle`) and a data attribute holding the selector of elements to modify.

```js
function toggleBySelector() {
  var target = $(this).data("selector");
  $(target).toggle();
}

$("button.toggle").on("click", toggleBySelector);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="toggle" data-selector="#single">Toggle Single</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button class="toggle" data-selector=".red">Toggle Red</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="red">Red Div</div>
  <div id="single">Single Div</div>
  <div class="red">Additional Red Div</div>
</div>
```

This binds the template to itself (or potentially other templates), but allows you to keep your DOM and script largely separate. Each button knows what elements it should toggle, using a jQuery selector in the `data-selector` attribute.

Using [jQuery's toggle method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), you don't need to keep track of which elements are shown or hidden, it will handle that for you.

Comment: @rekoDolph Edited with just that, misread the question initially.

Answer (score 2):

A general approach:

```js
function generalHideOrShow(element)
 {
  if (element instanceof Element)
  {
   //single element passed
   element = [element]; //mimic node list
  }
  if(element.length && element.length > 0 && element[0] instanceof Element)
  {
   //node list
   for (var i = 0; i < element.length; ++i)
   {

    if (element[i].getAttribute("data-hidden") == "true" )
    {
     $(element[i]).removeClass("hidden");
     element[i].setAttribute("data-hidden", false);
    }
    else
    {
     element[i].setAttribute("data-hidden", true);
     $(element[i]).addClass("hidden");
    }
    
   }
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }

  
 }

$("#button1").click(function(){
  
     generalHideOrShow($("div"));
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
  
     generalHideOrShow($("span"));
});

$("#button3").click(function(){
  
     generalHideOrShow(document.body.querySelectorAll("span:nth-child(odd)"));
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test div 1</div>
<div>test div 2</div>
<div>test div 3</div>
<div>test div 4</div>
<span>test span 1</span>
<span>test span 2</span>
<span>test span 3</span>
<span>test span 4</span>

<br />
<button id="button1">Click to toggle the divs</button>
<button id="button2">Click to toggle the spans</button>
<button id="button3">Click to toggle the even spans</button>
```

To use:
`generalHideOrShow( $("divs") );`
That will give an array of elements to the function.

This function will work with an `element` (passed with `document.getElementById("element")` for example), a Node list (passed with `document.querySelectorAll("div")` for example) and jQuery selectors.